# Python, got an unexpected keyword argument in my python code

Tags: python, function, keyword

My python code keeps giving me this error

this is the function I try to call with underneath it the code that calls it.

```
from sys import stdout
def print_nested_list(lijst, indent=False, indent_level=0, fh=stdout):
for x in lijst:
    if isinstance(x, list):
         print_nested_list(x, indent, indent_level+1, fh)
    else:
        if indent:
            for tabstop in range(indent_level):
                 print("\t", end='', file=fh)
    print(x, file=fh)



try:
with open(r'C:\Python34\headfirstpython\chapter 3\man_data.txt', 'w') as man_data:
    print_nested_list(man, fh=man_data)
with open(r'C:\Python34\headfirstpython\chapter 3\other_data.txt', 'w') as other_data:
    print_nested_list(other, fh=other_data)
```

IDLE gives this error when i try to run it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\headfirstpython\chapter 3\sketch1.py", line 25, in <module>
print_nested_list(man, fh=man_data)
TypeError: print_nested_list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fh'
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my function or the way I call my function?

Comment: first rule of debugging: assume that the error message is telling you the literal truth.

Comment: Is this your actual code? the indentation looks funny, and there's no `except` accompanying the `try`, and `man` and `other` aren't defined anywhere.

Comment: it's a part of the code and the function and the rest of the code are seperated in different files. I had a bit trouble uploading this code without setting of the 'You're code isnt in code blocks' warning from this site so that could have messed up my indentation.

Comment: @user3263958: see [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361) for help with formatting code.

Answer (score 9):

In the argument list, you don't have 'fh' - you have 'fh_id'. Try using 'fh' instead.

Comment: sorry it's an older version i posted. But with the fix it still gives the same error

Comment: @user3263958: no, it doesn't. If it gives the same error, you didn't fix it, or you're not running the code you think you're running.

Comment: Thanks, you were absolutely right! I forgot to update my function into my distribution of python so I ran an old function that wasn't updated with the hf argument. Again many thanks!

Comment: In my case, the code I was patching used `import packagename.subfile` instead of just `import subfile`, so Python looked for it in my import path instead of in the local directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your function doesn't *have* a `fh` keyword argument. It has a `fh_id` keyword argument though.

Either fix your function signature (rename `fh_id` to `fh`) or your call (use `fh_id` instead of `fh`).

Comment: sorry it's an older version i posted. But with the fix it still gives the same error

Comment: @user3263958: then post the *actual code* you are running. Make sure you are indeed running that code (introduce deliberate errors to make sure).

Comment: The same error still occures.

Comment: @user3263958: without your actual code, this isn't anything we can help with.